# Laravel getting results from model belongsToMany relationship back to controller

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 and Eloquent, I have 3 tables setup:

```
photos
+----+---------------+------------------+
| id |  photo_name   |  photo_location  |
+----+---------------+------------------+
|  1 | kittens.jpg   | C:\kittens.jpg   |
|  2 | puppies.jpg   | C:\puppies.jpg   |
|  3 | airplanes.jpg | C:\airplanes.jpg |
|  4 | trains.jpg    | C:\trains.jpg    |
+----+---------------+------------------+

photo_set (pivot table)
+------------+----------+
| set_id     | photo_id |
+------------+----------+
|          1 |        1 |
|          1 |        2 |
|          2 |        3 |
|          2 |        4 |
+------------+----------+

sets
+----+----------------+
| id |  description   |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | cute animals   |
|  2 | transportation |
+----+----------------+
```

I created a `belongsToMany` relationship in my `photos` and `sets` models to link these two together.

```
class Photo extends Model {

    public function sets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Set');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Set extends Model {

    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Photo');
    }

}
```

However I'm trying to reference the `$Sets->photos()` model function in my controller, so that given a set of `id=1`, I can return the `photo_location` value for each row `[C:\kittens.jpg,C:\puppies.jpg]`, but I don't know how to access it..

Also, I can "sort of" access this information in the view with:

```
@foreach($sets as $set)
    {{$set->images}}
@endforeach
```

but it looks like it only iterates through once and returns a json (?) of the necessary information, though I'm not sure how to parse that to regular HTML either.

So in short, I'm having trouble accessing this data (photo_location) from both the controller and the view

Comment: Why are you creating pivot table just create a column in photos set_id it will be easy for you manage relations right now you have 3 relations, and your model don't know about pivot table

Comment: I want the photos to be able to be apart of multiple sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Collection::lists()`

```
$locations = Set::find(1)->photos->lists('photo_location');
```

It will return an array `['C:\kittens.jpg', 'C:\puppies.jpg']`

http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_lists

Comment: The method `lists` has now been replaced by `pluck`. 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck

Answer (score 0):

In your controller try this :

```
$result = PhotoSet::where('set_id', $set_id)
          ->with('sets')
          ->with('photos')
          ->get();

$photo_location = $result->photos->photo_location;
```

here PhotoSet is the model for photo_set table, because it is a pivot table we will be able to access both sets and photos table from it.